# Angular Local storage

Tags: angularjs, angular-local-storage

I set my localStorageServiceProvider storage type to "localStorage". I am fine and it uses always the localStorage for any storage.

```
localStorageServiceProvider
          .setPrefix('VCMS')
          .setStorageType('localStorage')
          .setNotify(true, true)
```

In mu controller i am using like this

```
$scope.submit = function () {
        dataservice.authenticateUser($scope.userName, $scope.password)
            .then(
                    function (data) {
                        debugger;
                        console.log('Success');
                        localStorageService.remove(TOKENDATAKEY);
                        localStorageService.set(TOKENDATAKEY, data.access_token);
                        localStorageService.set(TOKENDATAKEY, data.access_token);
                    }
                );
    };
```

My question is how can I change the default storage type from localStorage to sessionStorage. I need to store a value in both localstorage and sessionstorage. How can we do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `localStorageService.setStorageType('sessionStorage');` not work?

Comment: I tried it but throws exception "TypeError: localStorageService.setStorageType is not a function"

Comment: What is the issue you are experiencing that is making you need to do this?

Comment: Also have you thought about using $cacheFactory instead?

Comment: I need to store 1 value in localStorage and another value in sessionStorage. Since my localStorageServiceProvider's default type is "localStorage", all my values are storing in localstorage only. I need to switch between the two storage types in my callback function

Comment: Use ngstorage ( https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) which supports both localStorage and sessionStorage at a time.

Comment: Thank you Subash Selvaraj. I think this will fulfill my need.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  Subash Selvaraj.
We can use on this one
http://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage